# Logging of access to reporting services reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging, reporting-services

We are designing a system where we intend to use reporting services for reporting.

The users will be able to create their own reports.

But, there is a requirement to log all access to data.

Anyone have an idea of how to do this? For example is it possible to store a PDF copy of every report that a user runs?

**Edit**

One way to solve this would be to read the data using a stored procedure, anyone know if this is possible with reporting servcies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution here on codeplex that allows you to monitor which reports have been run [Execution log importer](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2005!Server%20Management%20Sample%20Reports)